# Join one table to two separate one-to-many tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables, like so:

```
projects
| id | name       |
|----|------------|
| 1  | enterprise |
| 2  | discovery  |

widgets
| project_id | name            |
|------------|-----------------|
| 1          | saucer section  |
| 1          | pylons          |
| 2          | spinning saucer |
| 2          | angular pylons  |

sprockets
| project_id | name        |
|------------|-------------|
| 1          | engineering |
| 1          | bridge      |
| 1          | mess        |
| 2          | engineering |
| 2          | bridge      |
| 2          | mess        |
```

What I am trying to write is a query that gives me exactly ten results: essentially one for each row in `widgets` and `sprockets`, that looks like this:

```
result
| project_name | widget_name     | sprocket_name |
|--------------|-----------------|---------------|
| enterprise   | saucer section  | null          |
| enterprise   | pylons          | null          |
| enterprise   | null            | engineering   |
| enterprise   | null            | bridge        |
| enterprise   | null            | mess          |
| discovery    | spinning saucer | null          |
| discovery    | angular pylons  | null          |
| discovery    | null            | engineering   |
| discovery    | null            | bridge        |
| discovery    | null            | mess          |
```

Instead, my joins are combining to return 12 rows. Adding a group by seems to reduce it too much.

I've tried something like the following, but the joins are multiplied:

```
select
  p.name as project_name,
  w.name as widget_name,
  s.name as sprocket_name
from
  projects as p
left join widgets w on p.id = w.project_id
left join sprockets s on p.id = s.project_id;
```

The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767333/how-to-join-a-table-to-two-different-tables) [I've](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537779/multiple-tables-need-one-to-many-relationship) [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862918/common-one-to-many-table-for-multiple-entities) mostly focus on redesigning the database, however that is not an option for me. **How can I write a join to return the above ten rows from this dataset?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `UNION` of joins with each table.

```
SELECT p.name AS project_name, w.name AS widget_name, NULL AS sprocket_name
FROM projects AS p
INNER JOIN widgets AS w ON p.id = w.project_id

UNION ALL

SELECT p.name AS project_name, NULL AS widget_name, s.name AS sprocket_name
FROM projects AS p
INNER JOIN sprockets AS s ON p.id = s.project_id
```

Comment: The result of this is 20 rows, with some data that doesn't appear to correlate how I want. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oops, forgot the `ON` clauses

Comment: If you add "p" to the second line of "FROM projects AS p" I will accept this as the answer :)